# Python Data Types and Adding New Values

Tags: python, json

I have the following example result from an API request. My aim is to add more data to this 'route' result and the subsequent other 'route' results within the results. This will include information on what was sent to the API to generate this request.

```
results = 
[{u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value},
                           u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value}},
               u'copyrights': u'value',
               u'legs': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                        u'value': value},
                          u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                        u'value': value},
                          u'duration_in_traffic': {u'text': u'value',
                                                   u'value': value},
                          u'end_address': u'value',
                          u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                            u'lng': value},
                          u'start_address': u'value',
                          u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                          u'steps': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                        u'lng': value},
                                      u'html_instructions': u'value',
                                      u'polyline': {u'points': u'value'},
                                      u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                          u'lng': 0.value},
                                      u'travel_mode': u'value'},
                                     {u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                        u'lng': value},
                                      u'html_instructions': u’value’,
                                      u'maneuver': u’value’,
                                      u'polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                                      u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                          u'lng': value},
                                      u'travel_mode': u’value’},
                          u'via_waypoint': []}],
               u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
               u'summary': u’value’,
               u'warnings': [],
               u'waypoint_order': []}],
  u'status': u'OK'}]
```

I know that the API returns JSON but I have decoded this for use in Python via the Requests module.

When I run

```
print(type(results))
```

I get

```
<type 'list'>
```

I now want to add new information. For example,

```
'label': value
```

I am then attempting to use the extend function to add these new values.

I have tried

```
results.extend(["label":2,"label_2":3])
```

But I receive the following error

```
   results.extend(["label":2,"label_2":3])
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How else could I append/add/extend values to this response?

What I would like to achieve

```
results = 
[{u'routes': [{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value},
                           u'southwest': {u'lat': value,
                                          u'lng': value}},
               u'copyrights': u'value',
               u'legs': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                        u'value': value},
                          u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                        u'value': value},
                          u'duration_in_traffic': {u'text': u'value',
                                                   u'value': value},
                          u'end_address': u'value',
                          u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                            u'lng': value},
                          u'start_address': u'value',
                          u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                              u'lng': value},
                          u'steps': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                        u'lng': value},
                                      u'html_instructions': u'value',
                                      u'polyline': {u'points': u'value'},
                                      u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                          u'lng': 0.value},
                                      u'travel_mode': u'value'},
                                     {u'distance': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'duration': {u'text': u'value',
                                                    u'value': value},
                                      u'end_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                        u'lng': value},
                                      u'html_instructions': u’value’,
                                      u'maneuver': u’value’,
                                      u'polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
                                      u'start_location': {u'lat': value,
                                                          u'lng': value},
                                      u'travel_mode': u’value’},
                          u'via_waypoint': []}],
               u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u’value’},
               u'summary': u’value’,
               u'warnings': [],
               u'waypoint_order': []}],
  u'status': u'OK'}
  u'label': u'value'}]
```

UPDATE - further question - 
I have multiple 'routes' within 'results'. I send these requests in bulk and so I would like to add the relevant information that was sent for that particular request, and then append this information.

@martineau kindly helped and I have incorporated his edits. However, I am having issues associating the first value from the list I want to associate, with its respective result. Say I have four results and I want to append these 4 'origincoords' to the 4 different JSON responses.

Where

```
origincoords = ['51.41833327,0.115963078', '51.34666046,-0.210947524', '51.39574919,-0.045778021', '51.4178257,0.010449216']
```

The first set of coordinates should be associated with the first JSON result ('routes') and so on.

I have tried using the zip function, creating a new list that I have called output

```
output = (zip(results, origincoords))
```

When I print output, I get the values correctly appended at the end of the result -

```
u'summary': u'A20',
                u'warnings': [],
                u'waypoint_order': []}],
   u'status': u'OK'},
  '51.41833327,0.115963078'),
```

How do I add a label to this value? for example, I would like to see

```
  u'summary': u'A20',
                    u'warnings': [],
                    u'waypoint_order': []}],
       u'status': u'OK'},
      u'origincoord' : '51.41833327,0.115963078'),
```

Comment: You are using dictionary syntax in a list. What did you expect those labels to be added to? `results.extend()` will just add additional objects to the *end* of the list, nested dictionaries don't get updated using that syntax.

Comment: `["label":2,"label_2":3]` this looks more of the type dictionary

Comment: Can you please specify as where you want to insert the new element ?

Comment: where to add `"label":2,"label_2":3` values? means location in results??

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: thanks all. I would like the result to follow in the same fashion as 'status':'OK', at the end of what is shown above, within the nested dictionary. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ive edited the question to show expected result

Comment: another down vote.... Hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add information to the response, which is a list with one dictionary in it, which has a list under the key 'routes' which is a list with one dictionary in it — which is the one you want to modify by adding more key/value pairs to it. This can be done several ways:

```
results[0]['routes'][0]['label'] = 2
results[0]['routes'][0]['label_2'] = 3
```

or

```
results[0]['routes'][0].update({'label': 2, 'label_2': 3})
```

or

```
results[0]['routes'][0].update([('label', 2), ('label_2', 3)])
```

Regardless, you end up with something like:

```
results = [{'routes': [{'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 'value',
                                                 'lng': 'value'},
                        'status': 'OK',
                        'label': 2,
                        'label_2': 3
                          . . .
                       }
                      ]
           }
          ]
```

Comment: apologies, but I have a further query. Would you be able to advise? Many thanks

Comment: Feel free to post more questions here on SO.

Comment: thank you. I have edited my initial question here. You can see the additions at UPDATE above

Comment: I'll take a look at your follow-on question when I get a chance. You might get a quicker response by posting a completely new question.